# Parsing Elasticsearch json output in Python

Tags: python, json, elasticsearch

I am parsing data from Elasticsearch index and have received the data in json format as follows:

```
{
    "_shards": {
        "failed": 0,
        "skipped": 0,
        "successful": 5,
        "total": 5
    },
    "hits": {
        "hits": [
            {
                "_id": "wAv4u2cB9qH5eo0Slo9O",
                "_index": "homesecmum",
                "_score": 1.0870113,
                "_source": {
                    "image": "0000000028037c08_1544283640.314629.jpg"
                },
                "_type": "dataRecord"
            },
            {
                "_id": "wwv4u2cB9qH5eo0SmY8e",
                "_index": "homesecmum",
                "_score": 1.0870113,
                "_source": {
                    "image": "0000000028037c08_1544283642.963721.jpg"
                },
                "_type": "dataRecord"
            },
            {
                "_id": "wgv4u2cB9qH5eo0SmI8Z",
                "_index": "homesecmum",
                "_score": 1.074108,
                "_source": {
                    "image": "0000000028037c08_1544283640.629583.jpg"
                },
                "_type": "dataRecord"
            }
        ],
        "max_score": 1.0870113,
        "total": 5
    },
    "timed_out": false,
    "took": 11
}
```

I am trying to extract only the image parameter from json data and store it as an array.  I tried the following:

```
for result in res['hits']['hits']:
    post = result['_source']['image']
    print(post)
```

and this:

```
respars = json.loads(res['hits']['hits'][0]['_source'])['image']
print(json.dumps(respars, indent=4, sort_keys = True))
```

Both these throws an error:

```
TypeError: byte indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

I am sure similar problems were raised earlier here, but I couldn't get through this error. How can I fix it?

Comment: There is a nice package to handle elasticsearch: https://pypi.org/project/elasticsearch-dsl/

Comment: @andreihondrari  thank you will give this a try

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of going through the pain of manually handling the response, you could use the [Elasticsearch-DSL](https://pypi.org/project/elasticsearch-dsl/) package from PyPi.

Comment: thank you...the package straightaway helped me in parsing the data.

Answer (score 0):

To get all *image* in *_source* entry as list, you can use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html?highlight=list%20comprehension#list-comprehensions):

```
image_list = [source['_source']['image'] for source in res['hits']['hits']]
```

Output:

```
['0000000028037c08_1544283640.314629.jpg',
 '0000000028037c08_1544283642.963721.jpg',
 '0000000028037c08_1544283640.629583.jpg']
```